# How to read data from JSON file , Then Pass these values on web application form with the help of Xpath Locators and Then Write it in Excel file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, json

Steps :

Can you suggest the approach or share some sample script

1.Read data from JSON file
   - Method to Provide Data (JsonReader.getdata)
   - Get file location & File Name

2.In @Test(dataprovider='JSON File Data') -> Pass All values as Method Argument
   - Send all values one by One ( Xpath , Elementname , Sendkeys)
   - Fill the UI Header form with Values from JSON and Clickon Save

3.Write it in Excel file

Comment: What have you tried to do? Where is it giving you problems?

Comment: Akshay, you find some answer satisfiable, I would recommend marking it as accepted. It really motivates the community to continuing answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Read data from JSON

Google has a very good Java library to parse JSON in a structured way:
[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

The types you would use the most are [JSONObject](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) and [JSONElement](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html).

2 - Use the data in a test

I would suggest having in your dataprovide only the name of the JSON file. In the test, you can call a factory that would read the JSON file and generate a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object#JavaBeans) object.

E.g.,

```
@Test(dataprovider='JSON File Data')
public .... myTest(String jsonFileName) {
   TestDataModel testData = TestDataFactory.createTestDataFromJSON(jsonFileName);
   fillUserName(testData.getUserName());
   fillUserName(testData.getPassword());
   ...
   ExcelLogger.logTestDataInExcel(testData);
}
```

*TestDataModel* will represent the JSON file:

JSON:

```
{
  "userName": "Mario",
  "password": "Luigi"
}
```

POJO with [a bit of Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter):

```
public class TestDataModel {

@Getter @Setter
public final String userName;

@Getter @Setter
public final String password;

}
```

*TestDataFactory* and *ExcelLogger* will do the dirty work of interacting with the file system and performing the serialization/deserialization part.